# Docker: how to build an image from a non-master branch on Github repository

Tags: git, docker, github, branch

Is it possible to build an image from a non-master branch on a Github repository?

For example, I have the repository `//github.com/myAccount/docker-myImage` with a branch `development` that I would like to use for my image. Unfortunately, the following command only seems to allow building from the `master` branch:

```
docker build -t myAccount/myImage git://github.com/myAccount/docker-myImage
```

Here is the relevant documentation from `man docker build`:

> Building an image using a URL
>
> This will clone the specified Github repository from the URL and use it as context. The Dockerfile at the root of the repository is
>   used as Dockerfile. This only works if the Github repository is a
>   dedicated repository.
>
> ```
> docker build github.com/scollier/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/apache
> ```
>
> Note: You can set an arbitrary Git repository via the git:// schema.

Perhaps there is an alternative, like `docker build -t myAccount/myImage git://github.com/myAccount/docker-myImage:development`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`docker build -t myAccount/myImage https://github.com/myAccount/docker-myImage.git#development`

See [docker build command reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for more options.

Answer (score 6):

I proposed this question on `#docker` at the Freenode IRC and the user `scollier` contacted me and he said that he'll get back to me about this issue. I believe he is involved with the Docker documentation that I mentioned in my questions. In the meantime, I found a workaround by adding the following to my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN git clone something && cd something && git checkout branch
```

This solution seems to solve all my needs. Thanks for the support!

Comment: `RUN git clone -b branch something`

Answer (score 2):

The doc that you quoted itself mentions how you can specify the branch:

```
github.com/scollier/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/apache
```

Change `tree/master` to the branch you want and see.

Comment: Actually, this does not work. For example, when I executed the above command, I got the error: `repository
         'https://github.com/fedora-cloud/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/apache/'
         not found`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to create the branch before the docker container's git implementation can pull it from origin:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b branch_name
git pull origin branch_name
```